# Какие книги по "C" есть?

Tags: c, книги

Какие книги по "C" есть? Не C++, а именно С.

Answer (score 4):

Основная книга http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language и есть перевод.

Comment: Это каноничная книга, и этот ответ, возможно, самый подходящий, но было бы лучше если бы он был чуть подробнее.

Comment: А подробнее - это что? Керниган и Ритчи. Классика. Разумеется не c89 и с99, а именно "k&r c". Обложка у перевода 80-х годов была синяя. Что ещё?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы еще посоветовал справочник Шилдта http://wmate.ru/ebooks/book343.html в дополнение. Там популярно описаны отличия с89 от с99, плюс стандартная библиотека Си. Как по мне это самая адекватная книга по Си.

Answer (score 0):

После прочтения "K&R C" можно почитать Б. Керниган, Р. Пайк  "Практика программирования".
Отличная книга, хотя не только о C.