# Актуальный учебник с упражнениями/туториал по C для unix/linux на русском языке

Tags: linux, c, gcc

Знаю, что такие вопросы уже неоднократно поднимались, но, так или иначе, мне не удалось найти современный учебник с упражнениями, а ещё лучше набор упражнений (возможно я многого прошу, но желательно доступный онлайн) на русском языке.

Интересуют примеры, настройки среды, отладки на современных системах unix/linux с применением, например, какой-нибудь не очень бородатой версии gcc и прочих утилит.

Comment: Навскидку, пока так: - [Самоучитель. Программирование в Linux, 2012](https://vk.com/doc44301783_402529577?hash=687f66ba05f832a371&dl=e5840d7c4d3ec392ff)
- [UNIX. Профессиональное программирование, 2017](http://vk.com/doc272919530_362418072?hash=887814d9a6fe6cd355&dl=37ea93f7f9135177f9)

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос либо есть в вопросе "[Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)", либо должен быть добавлен именно туда. ))

Comment: @Majestio не хотите ли дополнить вопрос-список литературы?

Comment: Не совсем правильно разбили тему. ТС спрашивал не просто Си (и не С++) а Си для *NIX. А это своя специфика. Не столько язык как таковой, сколько системные вызовы.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Я конечно пока не специалист, но тогда уж лучше добавить в вопросы именно про Cи [первый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503204/Какие-свежие-книги-по-c-вам-известны) и [второй](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11217/Какие-книги-по-c-есть)

Comment: @SMetana похоже, я ошибся. Списка литературы именно про C у нас ещё нет (досадное недоразумение). Когда появится, там будет уместен отдельный параграф про C для *NIX.

Comment: @Majestio Спасибо, скачал, смотрю.

Comment: Я потому снова поднял этот вопрос, что Керниган и Ричи, которых по сути все рекомендуют в предыдущих вопросах - учебник написанный академическим языком, а я ищу что-то вроде инструкций от новичка к меньшему новичку. Я до этого изучал javascript ( и продолжаю) и для него есть куча упражнений с реальными фреймворками, библиотеками и утилитами (например, много отличных упражнений по node.js). Для С же почему-то в основном код оторванный от контекста и окружения, при том что на нём всё ещё активно пишут утилиты под линукс. Странная ситуация.

Comment: Если упражнения не обязательны, то вполне достойная -- [Linux. Системное программирование /Роберт Лав](http://www.spbk-spo.com/Professional/matematika_i_informatika/Lav_Linux_syst.pdf)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, раз уж пошла такая пьянка ... надо бы соорганизовать раздел "Программирование на C/C++ для различных OS/ABI". Это не только стильно, но и весьма практично!))) От себя: до сих пор в состоянии флюгера - "нужен ли C++ для андроида?". Плюсы есть - Цэ++ худо-бедно знаю, минусы - переносимость отвратительная. А Джаву не уважаю. Вот засада(

Comment: @Majestio Да, похоже на то, что я искал. Написано простым языком, с примерами, разбором утилит как по отдельности так и их взаимодействия. До сегодняшнего дня 1000 пользовался make, но по сути не знал что из себя представляет эта команда, спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что подобный раздел бы не помешал.

Comment: @SMetana, живите долго и счастливо! )))

Comment: @SMetana, make -- это функциональный язык программирования. Далеко не все и далеко не сразу сей факт осознают.

Comment: @Majestio работал в 2ГИС, там существенная часть мобильной разработки на плюсах. По крайней мере, все общие компоненты вроде трехмерной карты и различных алгоритмов.